# how to put between in Zend Framework query

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

anyone correct this query according to ZF.i  have a situation where user select differet parameters and on the base of that make my query

```
$user = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
$phone_service_id = $user->phone_service_id;

$start_date = $this->_getParam('start_date'); //02/07/2012
$end_date = $this->_getParam('end_date');     //02/21/2012
$option_call_log = $this->_getParam('option_call_log'); //COLUMN NAME
$option_call_log_asc_desc = $this->_getParam('option_call_log_asc_desc');  //ASC/DESC
```

i think i have a syntax error in query ,see it here

```
$select = $DB->select()
         ->from('CALL_LOG', array('caller_name','call_number','call_start_time','call_duration','call_direction'))
         ->where('phone_service_id = ?', $phone_service_id)
         ->where(DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN  $start_date  AND $end_date)
         ->order($option_call_log $option_call_log_asc_desc)
         ->limit(0,9);
```

whats wrong with this ??

Comment: Missing some quotes on `->where(DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN  $start_date  AND $end_date)`? This should throw a PHP syntax error long before it even gets to querying the db. Shouldn't it be something like `->where("DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN  $start_date  AND $end_date")`? (note inserted double-quotes)

Comment: what's the error you got? And try to `echo $select` and get what query you have found and run it on mysql.

Comment: In fact, it looks like you need quotes inside the `->order()` clause, too.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND )' at line 1

Comment: @GauravVashishtha the error is above

Comment: @Teknords try the below given solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BETWEEN clause is inclusive, the correct way is shown below:

```
$select = $DB->select()
         ->from('CALL_LOG', array('caller_name','call_number','call_start_time','call_duration','call_direction'))
         ->where('phone_service_id = ?', $phone_service_id)
         ->where("DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%m/%d/%Y') >= ?",  $start_date)
         ->where("DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%m/%d/%Y') <= ?",  $end_date)
         ->order("".$option_call_log." ".$option_call_log_asc_desc)
         ->limit(0,9);
```

try the above code and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I have make change in the answer. So now check it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will not utilize any index on the date and would require a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

zend db also used in magento so i found out the way.

```
$sql = $read->select()
                ->from(array('g' => $res->getTableName('geoloc')));

        $whereSql = "INET_ATON('{$remoteAddr}') BETWEEN g.start AND g.end";

        $sql = $sql->where($whereSql); //echo $sql;exit;
        $result = $read->fetchRow($sql);
```

the output will be like below:

> SELECT `g`.* FROM `geoloc` AS `g` WHERE
>   (INET_ATON('41.98.30.186') BETWEEN g.start AND g.end)

hope it helps.